# What would a lizardly phonetic alphabet be?

Tags: anatomy, reptiles, speech

The international phonetic alphabet system contains all sounds that a human can make. However, humans are not lizards, but mammals, and hence have many features that let us make more complex sounds

The basic example will be an intelligent lizard that speaks through its mouth. Its mouth has the following features:

- Its lips are fused to its jaws, and cannot move independently from them. There is also no gap between the lips and jaws
- Its front teeth are sharp, but not sharp enough to cut the tongue during normal speech
- It has no alveolar ridge
- Its tongue is thick and can move around the mouth or become deeper or shallower, just as a human tongue can
- It has no soft palate, and its hard palate is divided down the middle into two halves and cannot be closed
- It has a larynx, which functions similarly to a human larynx

Based on this anatomy, what sort of phonemes could a lizard with such an anatomy produce from its mouth?

Comment: Very obviously, the answer to the question *"what sort of phonemes could a lizard with such an anatomy produce from its mouth" is "lizardly phonemes". The question cannot be answered until we meet a speaking lizard, learn to understand its speech, analize it, and then devise a description system and a set of symbols for the phonemes of its language. (And no, the IPA does not contain all sounds that a human can make". Only those phonemes and most phones used in normal speech. For example, humans can make a sound by snapping their fingers, or by blowing air with the tongue between their lips.)

Comment: @AlexP The's a little harsh. It would probably be possible to simulate this, and see what sorts fo vocalizations are possible (to some extent). I'm sure that with a few million in grant money, and a team of biophysicists I could get him the answers he wants in as little as 3 years. That said, IK, are we even aware of any real world lizards that make any sort of vocalization at all? I'm coming up blank. I can tell you what a frog sounds like (loud little bastards sometimes), but I can't think of a single lizard species known for such.

Comment: @JohnO: Human speech does not use all the sounds that humans can make with their mouths, so I see no reason why lizard speech would. Additionally, lizards have a very limited hearing range, so that most of the possible sounds would not be heard and thus would not be used. Additionally again, human phones/phonemes are almost *never* described in physical terms, but always in linguistic terms; we mostly *do not care* about the physical aspects of the sound /t/, but we care very much that it is a (1) voiceless (2) dental (or alveolar) (3) plosive; we *need* to analize lizard speech.

Comment: While it doesn't make your question less interesting, remember to make them [wiggle their head](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1zepbLbco0&t=375s)  as they speak. First, because it is very fun just imagining it ; Then, because the more you diversify your communication channels, the easier your lizards will understand each other. It is especially true since if we take from real-world, lizards are more the sight-kind than the hearing one.

Comment: I assume a vocalizing lizard species would evolve better hearing in their vocal range, similar to our sensitivity at 1-4kHz

Comment: I'm going to VTC:Opinion-Based based on [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/7317/29081) from our sister Stack, [linguistics.se], which was closed for the same reason. We can't definitively identify the number of phonemes we humans can use despite hundreds of thousands of years of experience. Starting with that, subdividing the *possible* phonemes into a *plausible alphabet* (considering there are 7,100 languages spoken on Earth *today* and an estimate 31,000 language throughout history) is pure 100% aesthetics and opinion-based. HOWEVER...

Comment: ... There's a difference between "what would a phonetic alphabet be?" (absolutely opinion-based) and "what sort of phonemes could be produced?" I could be convinced that the second question (assuming the first were eliminated) is a request for a [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) given the restrictions you've imposed. So I'll retract my vote if you [edit] the post and ask the one and only one question I think can be embraced.

Comment: BTW, an excellent article making a practical point is [The 800 phonemes of the tiniest linguists](https://www.csmonitor.com/The-Culture/Verbal-Energy/2016/0128/The-800-phonemes-of-the-tiniest-linguists). The point it makes is that the difference between the sounds a creature *could* make and the sounds a creature *does* make in regard to language has a lot to do with the language. Getting from "here's the physiology of my creature" to "here's my creature's language" is not at all a straightforward process.

Comment: @AlexP Still sets the upper bound. And when the upper bound is zero... I contend that making speech "lizard-like" is just a null concept, when there's exactly nothing to work with in terms of lizard vocalization. It's an odd choice, really, given that most other animals that breath air have something to start from in that regard. I think newly-hatched alligators make peeping sounds and the adults bellow, but they're not really lizards either.

Comment: Oo, this is an excellent question! Two points of clarification would be fantastic! 1. How far anterior is the hard palate cleft? Like, all the way through the anterior maxilla or are you talking more of a V notch posteriorly? Also, is there any mucosal covering for the cleft? Or are the nasal and oral cavities essentially one? Second, Are the teeth exposed when the mouth is closed, or do the lips form a seal, even if they are not mobile? (This will all make a huge difference!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A Narrow Answer About Lizard-Human Pidgin

Sure, the broadest interpretation of this question may be unanswerable. If you're creating a fantasy creature, you could give it all sorts of exotic signalling apparatus or linguistic instincts. (Maybe their language consists mostly of skin-color changes.)

But we can answer a narrower question: What kind of phonemes could be spoken both by humans *and* by a fantasy species with the specific anatomical features you describe? In other words, what phonemes would humans and your lizans use to speak to each other?

Well, you specify that this creature has:

- a human-like tongue (which can presumably block air flow for plosives and the like)
- a human-like larynx
- teeth which can be used in speech.

So it sounds like you've designed them to be able to use dental and laryngeal consonants (except for the nasals), and some form of vowels. That seems like enough to form a humanesque language.

The tongue does a lot of the work for vowels, but the lips and other bits are also important for shaping them. Let's just assume there's some subset of vowels found to be mutually comprehensible and move on, though, since I'm not sure how specific we can be there.

The dental consonants give you both *th* sounds, variants on *t,d,l,s,z*, as well as the dental ejective and click. The dental versions of s and z sound hissy when I say them, so that's on-theme.

The laryngeal consonants are also on-theme because a snake's hiss is glottal (it's more of a 'hhhhh' than a 'sssss'). If I were designing this language, I'd lean hard into the pharyngeal and glottal sounds.

But even just sticking to English phonology (or sounds which are close to English's), you'd have 9 consonants, including the glottal stop. That's small, but not unreasonably so. Hawaiian only has ~8 consonants, for example.

...
Actually, that gives me an idea for a horrifically lazy bit of language building. Just take Hawaiian and do a swap the consonants to make them purely dental/laryngeal.
(K to T, M to S, N to Z, P to D, and W to TH,. H/L/' stay the same.)
Though it might stretch suspension of disbelief if your lizards greet each other with "aloha".

Comment: Hard to say *aloha* without the ability to round the lips... Closest thing would be /alˈəha/.